# Beamer: Arrowing forward with "split frames" and backwards with non-split frames. Is it possible?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I faced an annoying situation using the beamer class. The situation:

During a presentation it is helpful to use "split" frames (produced by commands like `\pause` etc.). But when there is a discussion or a question/answer part after the presentation, the split frames are annoying. Because when you would like to go back to a certain piece of information, it takes ages to get there.

I wonder if there is the possibility to arrow forward using split frames and to arrow back "jumping" from non-split frame to non-split frame.

Comment: Are you using some navigation symbols or any `miniframes`-like outer theme? Also you can place skip forward backward buttons wherever you wish..

Comment: Before I just used my keyboard. Using the navigation symbols works perfectly. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can simply be solved by using the default `beamer navigation symbols`

[image]

or one can make use of the navigation symbols that appear in the outer themes;
`smoothbars` or `miniframes` variants for quick jumps.

[image]