# How to jump to the first slide of the previous frame when pressing page up in presentation?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I have a beamer presentation with frames A, B, and C.

Frame B has several slies (made with overlays) that are shown in a timed sequence finishing at at frame C.

Then, at frame C, I'd like to press the page up key to go back to the beginning of frame B instead of going back to the last slide of frame B, which is putting me back into frame C.
How can I do this?

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Asking in another way: How can I redefine to which frame do PageUp and PageDown jump to?

Comment: This is related if clicking instead of a keyboard shortcut is allowed: [Beamer: Arrowing forward with “split frames” and backwards with non-split frames. Is it possible?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39100/)

Comment: Yes it is related, and it seems that that is the only solution as no one answers my question